# Is it a leaky abstraction if implementation of interface calls Dispose

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, loose-coupling

Consider this code:

```
public class MyClass()
{
  public MyClass()
  {    
  }

  public DoSomething()
  {
    using (var service = new CustomerCreditServiceClient())
    {
       var creditLimit = service.GetCreditLimit(
         customer.Firstname, customer.Surname, customer.DateOfBirth);       
    }
  }
}
```

We now want to refactor it to loosely couple it. We end up with this:

```
public class MyClass()
{
  private readonly ICustomerCreditService service;

  public MyClass(ICustomerCreditService service)
  {
     this.service= service;
  }

  public DoSomething()
  {
     var creditLimit = service.GetCreditLimit(
       customer.Firstname, customer.Surname, customer.DateOfBirth);       
  }
}
```

Looks ok right? Now any implementation can use the interface and all is good.

What if I now say that the implementation is a WCF class and that the using statement before the refactoring was done was there for a reason. ie/to close the WCF connection.

So now our interface has to implement a `Dispose` method call or we use a factory interface to get the implementation and put a using statement around that.

To me (although new to the subject) this seems like a leaky abstraction. We are having to put method calls in our code just for the sake of the way the implementation is handling stuff.

Could someone help me understand this and confirm whether I'm right or wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You can make your interface inherit from Dispose

Comment: True or implement its own Dispose. Either way, having to call Dispose is leaky isnt it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is a leaky abstraction when you let `ICustomerCreditService` implement `IDisposable`, since you've now written `ICustomerCreditService` with a specific implementation in mind. Further more, this communicates to the consumer of that interface that it could dispose that service, which might not be correct, especially since in general, a resource should be disposed by the one who creates it (who has the ownership). When you inject a resource into a class (using constructor injection for instance), it is not clear if the consumer is given the ownership.

So in general the one responsible of creating that resource should dispose it.

However, in your case, you can simply prevent this from even happening by implementing a non-disposable implementation of `ICustomerCreditServiceClient` that simply creates and disposes the WCF client within the same method call. This makes everything much easier:

```cs
public class WcfCustomerCreditServiceClient
    : ICustomerCreditServiceClient
{
    public CreditLimit GetCreditLimit(Customer customer)
    {
        using (var service = new CustomerCreditServiceClient())
        {
            return service.GetCreditLimit(customer.Firstname,
                customer.Surname, customer.DateOfBirth);       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. The only thing I would say there is that there is another level of abstraction but that might not be a bad thing per se

Comment: @Jon: There is no new level of abstraction. You already defined that `ICustomerCreditServiceClient` abstraction. The difference is that your WCF proxy doesn't implement it, but no new abstractions where added. Doing things like this prevents you from complicating you IoC configuration.

Comment: Maybe my terminiology is wrong. I meant another level, so MyClass calls WcfCustomerCreditServiceClient which calls CustomerCreditServiceClient

Comment: @Jon: True. But will this ever be a problem?

Comment: If this is the only function called on that interface this was also my first idea. However, when there is not only one call to the interface but several (withing then original using-block), then this might become slow, as every call connects and disconnects...

Comment: @FrankB: That's true. When the performance gets a problem, you will need to move the scope up of the resource. One step up is to use a factory (as you wrote in your answer). Next step up is to let the DI/IoC container dispose it. For instance, when running in a web environment, you can register it as a 'per web request' lifestyle, which means only one instance is created during the lifetime of a single web request. If you're not running in a web environment, you'd probably need some scoping, as Dennis Traub explains.

Comment: While factories are in general a good solution (and are easy to follow), they force you to have another abstraction in your system. So in this case I would normally start with the wrapper implementation in my answer and if that isn't fast enough, move to a 'per web request' or 'lifetime scope' lifestyle, as Dennis explains.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the lifecycle of the `customerCreditService` in the calling code. How should `MyClass` know if the service is still needed by the caller? If caller is responsible for cleaning up its resources then `MyClass` doesn't need to be disposable.

```
// calling method

using (var service = new CustomerCreditServiceClient()) {
    var myClass = new MyClass(service);
    myClass.DoSomething();
}
```

*Update:* In the comments OP mentioned the use of an IoC like Ninject. The code then could look like this:

```
IKernel kernel = ...;

using (var block = kernel.BeginBlock())
{
    var service = block.Get<ICustomerCreditService>();
    var myClass = new MyClass(service);
    myClass.DoSomething();
}
```

The `kernel.BeginBlock()` creates an activation block. It makes sure that the resolved instances are disposed when the block ends.

Comment: But this will all be done with an IOC container so you'd need to specify something with that. I think Ninject allows you to call a dispose on a dependency implementation when you configure it

Comment: Then you can have the IoC container resolve and dispose of the `CustomerCreditServiceClient`. There still is no need to implement `IDisposable.Dispose()` in `MyClass`.

Comment: You would not pass the the kernel around like that

Comment: This is just a simplified example. You never mentioned an IoC container in the first place and I just tried to extend my answer according to your comment. Please update your question if the use of a container is so important. OTOH: Using an IoC container is considered an anti-pattern itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the Dispose of the `ICustomerCreditService` where it has been instantiated as `MyClass` now has no idea of the lifecycle of `ICustomerCreditService`.

Comment: But this will all be done with an IOC container so you'd need to specify something with that. I think Ninject allows you to call a dispose on a dependency implementation when you configure it

Answer (score 1):

Starting again with the first implementation, I would try to add a getInterface-Request to the Class, so that the implementation could stay more or less the same. Then it can safely call `Dispose` (effectively it only defers the creation of the interface implementation, but stays in control of its life cycle):
(c#-code not verified...)

```
public class MyClass()
{
  public delegate ICustomerCreditService InterfaceGetter;
  private InterfceGetter getInterface;
  public MyClass(InterfaceGetter iget)
  {
    getInterface = iget;
  }
  public DoSomething()
  {
    using (var customerCreditService = getInterface())
    {
       var creditLimit = customerCreditService.GetCreditLimit(customer.Firstname, customer.Surname, customer.DateOfBirth);       
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I find your answer a bit vague, but you're basically advising to inject a factory that allows creating that instance (+1 for that). In general, factories are good, since it is clear that the caller gets the ownership of the instance created, and it is clear it needs to dispose that instance. You'll still need to implement `IDisposable` on the `ICustomerCreditService` though, which is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. But that’s a necessary evil. The very *existence* of the `IDisposable` interface is a leaky abstraction. Leaky abstractions are simply an everyday fact of programming. Avoid them where possible but don’t fret when you can’t – they are ubiquitous anyway.

Comment: @FrankB Uhm … could you elaborate? After all, this isn’t an opinion with which to agree or disagree, it’s a *fact* – facts can’t be disagreed with, only their evaluation. If you think I’ve made a mistake in the facts or their evaluation then please tell me so and I’ll correct that.

Comment: @Steven Same for you. See previous comment. Incidentally, I’ve seen your answer just now, and this is indeed a non-leaky way to handle *this particular case*. My answer was more general though.

Comment: @KonradRudolph IDisposable is there exactly to be non-leaky. If you mean that it is easy to do it wrong; then yes, that's bad. But thats not IDisposables fault... It is a clean way of keeping unmanaged stuff under control. btw: You did not elaborate on what makes it leaky?

Comment: @FrankB That’s not what “leaky abstraction” means. It has got nothing to do with resource leaks. Leaky abstraction means leaking implementation details (such as: “this resource needs to be disposed manually”) to the public interface.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ok, understood. However, I still cant completely agree to your overall statement... (but that's off topic for this question)

Comment: `IDisposable` is by itself not a leaky abstraction. `IDisposable` is a clear contract that communicates that the type implementing it has resources that can be deterministically cleaned up. However, when you apply `IDisposable` to another interface, that interface can become a leaky abstraction. The reason is that there's no way to foresee all possible implementations of an interface and therefore you can always come up with a disposable implementation of practically any interface.

Comment: When you implement `IDisposable` on an interface you are leaking knowlegde of an implementation through to the interface design. However, when you implement `IDisposable` on an implementation, you don't have a leaky abstraction. You just state that this implementation manages resources. Therefore, `IDisposable` itself is not a leaky abstraction, and that's why I don't agree with you.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for clearing this up. But this leaves us in an interesting situation since I claim that yes, `IDisposable` *is* always a leaky abstraction, at its most fundamental level. It signals something about an object for which the *user* of the object doesn’t care about the least bit; namely, that it requires explicit resource management. This isn’t the *purpose* of an object, it’s an inconvenient detail.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The *user* of the *abstraction* doesn't care about `IDisposable` (that's why an interface should not implement `IDisposable`), but the *user* of the *implementation* does care about *IDisposable*, since he is responsible of creating and disposing it. A leaky abstraction means that implementation details are leaking through the abstraction. However, when you implement `IDisposable` on the implementation, there is no knowledge leaking; just communicating what is needed.

Comment: @Steve If I’m using `System.Drawing.Graphics` then I’m the user of that class. Yet that class implements (*needs to implement*) `IDisposable`. Thus `Graphics` leaks details about its internal implementation (in terms of GDI+ by the operating system, where handles have to be allocated and disposed).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: The fact that some objects need deterministic disposal is an intrinsic part of how .NET (or perhaps even any computer system) works. If you take this abstraction (over the hardware) into consideration, than yes; that is indeed a leaky abstraction. In that case resource management itself is the abstraction, while I was talking about the  `ICustomerCreditService` as abstraction. Conclusion: we were both right :-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph You almost have me - but to turn this on its head: You can have an implementation where the Dispose does nothing (because that implementation does not need it). In this case the user thinks he knows something about the implementation, while in fact doesnt. IDisposable just asks the user to tell it when finished. Isn't that more of a behaviour (I didnt find a better term) than a leak?

Comment: @Steve Yes, resource management *is* a leaky abstraction. [Joel Spolsky has written a seminal essay about this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) where he concludes “All non-trivial abstractions, to some degree, are leaky.” – and he’s absolutely right.