# MVC Simple Injector and RegisterPerWebRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

As per the Simple Injector documentation, I'm instantiating my repository objects for an MVC application as such:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>();
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IOrderRepository, SqlOrderRepository>();
```

But I've just found the documentation also states:

In contrast to the default behavior of Simple Injector, these extension methods ensure the created service is disposed (**when such an instance implements IDisposable**).

https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObjectLifestyleManagement#PerWebRequest

**Question:** Does this mean when using RegisterPerWebRequest, my objects need to implement IDisposable so they get disposed at the end of the web request (i.e. below code)?

Side-note: I believe using WebRequestLifestyle, RegisterInitializer, RegisterForDisposal, also requires objects implementing IDisposable.

Example code (interface and implementation) below.

```
public interface IUserRepository : IDisposable
{
    ...
}

public class SqlUserRepository : IUserRepository, IDisposable
{
    ...
    ...
    ...


    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in general your interfaces should not implement `IDisposable`; only your [implementations should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259534/is-it-a-leaky-abstraction-if-implementation-of-interface-calls-dispose). Otherwise you're leaking implementation details and are violating the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Comment: Did not know this re leaking. I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclosure: I have not used SimpleInjector.

From what I gather from reading that, **no, you don't need to implement `IDisposable`**.

What it's saying is that, by default, objects that are registered are not disposed of. That is, SimpleInjector won't attempt to call `Dispose()` if you register the object by means other than per web request.

However, using `RegisterPerWebRequest()` means that `Dispose()` will be called if the object is an `IDisposable` unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Apologies, but I'm confused with your statement "no, you don't need to implement IDisposable". Since I'm working on an MVC application, each web request is a new 'session', therefore I should be implementing IDispose in my repository objects (when using RegisterPerWebRequest) so Simple Injector can dispose and free up memory.

Comment: Sorry, my statement was being generic. What I meant was that, in general, classes don't **have** to implement `IDisposable`. Whether or not you implement `IDisposable` is up to you and depends on the object. If an object does implement `IDisposable` you can rest assured that Simple Injector will dispose of the object at the end of the web request.

Comment: If you're asking if you need to implement the code that you've supplied, then the answer might be no. Only implement `IDisposable` if you have unmanaged resources that need cleaning up or some other reason and you expect the `Dispose()` method to be called in order to *finalise* your object..

Answer (score 5):

A few side notes here, it seems that you are implementing the full dispose pattern here, but you can simplify this when you make your `SqlUserRepository` `sealed`. This allows you to do the following:

```
public sealed class SqlUserRepository : IUserRepository, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Since `SqlUserRepository` is sealed, no one can derive from it and there is therefore:

- There is no need for the virtual protected Dispose(bool) method.
- There is no need to call `SuppressFinalize`, because that is only needed when there is a finalize method, but since you don't implement it and you're sure there's no derived type, you don't need to call it.

There is also no need to have the `disposed` flag, since you are delegating the dispose to the `_context`, but it should be resilient to calling dispose multiple times; that is defined in the `IDisposable` contract.

Further more, if you inject that context object into the constructor of your `SqlUserRepository`, there is no need at all to implement disposable on the `SqlUserRepository`. You only have to register that context with a web request lifestyle and Simple Injector will dispose that for you.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented a dispose pattern. Your advice is just fantastic! Thanks! Correcting my dispose code now.