# DbContext object has been disposed: how can I prevent the object to be disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using asp.net mvc, Entityframework 6 and Unity for DI scenarios.

I couldn't find out why my DbContext object are being disposed too early.

I injected the GenericWoU class into `PeopleController` class. When I call the ListPerson action everything works ok however the DbContext is disposed. So if I try to edit any person of the list, the following error appears:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been
>   disposed

how can I prevent the DbContext to be disposed so early?

Here is my Generic Unit of Work class:

```
    public class GenericUoW : IDisposable, IGenericUoW
    {
        private readonly DbContext entities = null;
        public Dictionary<Type, object> repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public GenericUoW(DbContext entities)
        {
            this.entities = entities;
        }

    public IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)) == true)
        {
            return repositories[typeof(T)] as IRepository<T>;
        }

        IRepository<T> repo = new GenericRepository<T>(entities);
        repositories.Add(typeof(T), repo);
        return repo;
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                entities.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Here is my `GenericRepository` class:

```
class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext entities = null;
    private DbSet<T> _objectSet;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext _entities)
    {
        entities = _entities;
        _objectSet = entities.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Func<T, bool> predicate = null)
    {
        if (predicate != null)
        {
            return _objectSet.Where(predicate);
        }

        return _objectSet.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public T Get(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.First(predicate);
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.Attach(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _objectSet.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

Here is my ContainerBootstrapper class:

```
public class ContainerBootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        return container;
    }
    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        DbContext entities = new TeijonStuffEntities();
        container.RegisterInstance(entities);

        GenericUoW GUoW = new GenericUoW(entities);
        container.RegisterInstance(GUoW);

        MvcUnityContainer.Container = container;
        return container;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not implement `IDisposable` on `GenericUoW`. Do not inject dispose injected depenencies, because the consuming class does not have the ownership of the dependencies (only the Composition Root and the container do) and it does not know whether or not the dependency (the `DbContext` in this case) should be disposed or not. Removing the `Dispose` functionality might actually solve your problem, although it is hard to tell, because enough details are missing to describe the exact cause.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259534/is-it-a-leaky-abstraction-if-implementation-of-interface-calls-dispose

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30287923/264697

Comment: It worked!! Can you rewrite your comment as an answer so I can upvote and accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general problem is that your components take ownership over its dependencies by disposing it. A component never knows what the lifetime of its dependencies are and whether they might be used by other components later on (possibly even in the same request). So this makes it dangerous (or even plain wrong) to dispose dependencies.

Instead, as a general rule of thumb it is the one who creates a component, is responsible of its disposal. Since in your case Unity creates that object, it should dispose it (and it will).

This means that you should remove all the dispose functionality from `GenericUoW`. Not only is this the only correct way, it is actually much less code to maintain, since this not only affects `GenericUoW`, but also all the possible direct and indirect consumers of `GenericUoW`. In your design they all had to implement `IDisposable`. When applying DI correctly, you can leave this out and this can have a huge impact on the maintainability of your code.

Long story short, change the `GenericUoW` to the following:

```
public sealed class GenericUoW : IGenericUoW
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> repositories =new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    private readonly DbContext entities;

    public GenericUoW(DbContext entities)
    {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (!repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T))) {
            IRepository<T> repo = new GenericRepository<T>(entities);
            repositories.Add(typeof(T), repo);
        }

        return (IRepository<T>)repositories[typeof(T)];
    }

    public void SaveChanges() {
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```